# Which Java Web Service Framework do you prefer?

Tags: java, web-services

I am gonna implement web service in Java but before implementation I will decide which framework I should use. Simplicity and running on JBoss 4.2.3 Platform are the requirements.

What is your suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using an additional technology <strike>stack</strike> component, why not use the `@WebService` annotation introduced in EJB3. JBoss 4.2.3 [supports](http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=614346&group_id=22866) EJB3

[Two](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html) [examples](http://blog.redstream.nl/2008/02/03/creating-an-ejb3-webservice-with-maven2-running-on-jboss-421/)

Using EJB3 Web Services guarantees that you web services will run on any Java EE compliant server without any modifications to the server.

Comment: I have used JBoss-WS with EJB 3 support. It is simple. I had tried before but my jboss is customized so some jars are not included. I added these jars in my project. Anyway JBoss-WS is good choice for Java Web Service

Answer (score 3):

Since JBoss provides JavaEE features, you can simply take a look at [JAX-WS](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/), annotate your EJBs, and let JBoss handle everything from there.

Otherwise you can look at [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) and for JBoss + CXF [see here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-StackCXFUserGuide)

Comment: I have tried it, JAX-WS CXF implementation but I couldn't successfully deploy on JBoss 4.2.3

Answer (score 1):

1. Axis2 on Tomcat 6
2. JAX-WS on Tomcat 6

Quick, Fast and Easy